# How to refresh HTTP request cache?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, httprequest

### Current state

Many answers exist for

1. Refresh page cache but not the javascript-issued requests' cache
2. Issue `cache: false` ajax request
3. Set `Expires` header at server-side

### Goal state

However, is there a way to do either of the following at client-side?

1. Refresh the page without (page cache AND requests cache); in fact, the CMD+SHIFT+R reload achieves this purpose on Edge(Mac OS)
2. Make an ajax request not only retrieve new data(by new timestamp) but also use this data to overwrite the original request cache.

Example: after page `/names` loads, Javascript GET `/api/names?id=<id>`; ajax method would GET `/api/names?id=<id>&_=<timestamp>`, but this does not refresh cache for`/api/names`

### Purpose

Use cache to increase load speed, while also preserving users' flexibility to retrieve updated data.

Comment: I don't think there's a separate cache for AJAX requests. There's just a single cache for the responses to all `GET` requests.

Comment: And there's no API to refresh the cache. The usual solution to avoid cached data is to add a cache-buster to the URL.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I'm just using ajax as an example, where the cache-less request is not the original URL, os does not overwrite cache

Comment: JavaScript has no direct access to the cache. There's no way to bypass the cache, and no way to force refresh the cache. If you use a cache-buster to force reloading the data, you can't make that refresh a cache entry with a different URL.

Comment: There is a way to bypass the cache (more precisely, force revalidation) from the client side: use the [`Cache-Control: no-cache`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4) header in the request.

Comment: Also for Safari to work, add the header `Vary: *`